# How to get current use openapi version in code C# .net 5

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, .net-5, swashbuckle

How can I get "openapi" version through code to put it into an own Controller response ?

When you print the openapi generated JSON, it starts with

```
{
"openapi": "3.0.1",
"info": {
...
}
```

and I want to get the value "3.0.1" as string. Is there a way to access it into a controller like with Dependency Injection or something like that ?

Example:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/my-app/openapi-version")]
public class OpenApiVersionController: ControllerBase
    private IOptions<Configuration> Configuration;
    // Use DI to access to my own configuration
    public OpenApiVersionController(IOptions<Configuration> configuration)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("")]
    public ActionResult<OpenApiVersion> GetOpenApiVersion()
    {
        string version = // What should I write here ?
        Ok(new OpenApiVersion(version));
    }
}
```

I use .net5 with Swashbuckle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of old thread but I finally found a workaround (not so pretty but it works):

```
[ApiController] [Route("api/my-app/openapi-version")] 
public class OpenApiVersionController : ControllerBase 
{

  private IOptions<Configuration> Configuration;

  // Use DI to access to my own configuration
  public OpenApiVersionController(IOptions<Configuration> configuration)
  {
    this.Configuration = configuration;
  }

  [HttpGet, Route("")]
  public ActionResult<OpenApiVersion> GetOpenApiVersion()
  {
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string openApiVersion = $"Unable to get version. Default version: 3.0.1";
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string uri = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api/v1/xxxxx.openapi.json");  // same as define in c.SwaggerEndpoint("/api/v1/xxxxx.openapi.json", ...) in Startup.cs
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            foreach (string s in json.Split(","))
            {
                if (s.Contains("openapi")) // could certainly be improved with regex !
                {
                    try
                    {
                        openApiVersion = s.Split(":")[1]?.Replace("\"", "")?.Trim();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // parsing error, default openApiversion is returned
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    OpenApiVersion version = new OpenApiVersion // model for endpoint return
    {
        appVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location).FileVersion,
        dotNetVersion = Environment.Version.ToString(),
        openApiVersion = openApiVersion
    };
    Ok(version);
  }
}
```

Idea is to read the generated JSON as it contains the OPENAPI version

Answer (score 1):

You can get requested version this way

```
HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion()
```

Comment: HttpContext seems not have GetRequestedApiVersion into it. Shall I add it through a middleware or smth like this ? As HttpContext does not simpy know that I'm using openapi, I'm a bit confused

Comment: it's inside `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`, it also can be installed with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer` as a dependency